# mongoid - deleting child objects from a parent in a reference 1..N relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I notice when I do:

```
parent.children.delete_all(condition: {obj_id: obj.id})
```

and then I do:

```
parent.children
```

I still see a reference to the object I tried to delete.

If I instead do:

```
parent = Parent.where(id) #get the parent again from db
parent.children
```

I notice that the child is missing.

How do I ensure that when I delete a child, it deletes it from the db, and removes the reference from the array in one action?

Comment: You could use `parent.children(true)` to update the cache...

Comment: @klump. You solution works. But where is this mentioned in the mongoid docs that this has to be done after a delete? I'm having the same issue and I was hoping to find somewhere in their documentation that mentions you have to do this.

Comment: I do not know where this is documented, but the object does not get synced with the database when you delete children (I think this is expected behaivor). To "sync" your object with the database again you need to refresh the cache. Its just logical :P

Answer (score 1):

Try using `destroy_all` instead of `delete_all`.